# List all combinations in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, list, combinations

In VB.NET, how do I list all of the possible combinations from a list. I want to be able to use method where you pass in the parameters to specify the number of items in each combination . In my case I only want 2. I do not want to see the same combination in a different order. And I want to record this information in a listbox. I have tried request from other posts but they just don't seem to work for me.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty way of doing this.  It is very inefficient and is by no means the "best" way.  Once the code hist the "stop", `uniqueResults` will contain the items you want to add to the listbox.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim source As New List(Of String)({"cat", "dog", "hamster", "goat"})
        Dim results As List(Of List(Of String)) = Combine(source, 3)
        Dim uniqueResults As List(Of String) = Filter(results)
        stop
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Builds an N length list of all possible combinations of Source
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="source">a list of strings containing the possible items</param>
    ''' <param name="length">the length of the list of items to return</param>
    Private Function Combine(source As List(Of String), length As Integer) As List(Of List(Of String))
        Dim ret As New List(Of List(Of String))
        Combine(source, length, New List(Of String), ret)
        Return ret
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Recursivly builds an N length list of all possible combinations of Source
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="source">a list of strings containing the possible items</param>
    ''' <param name="length">the number of items remaining to add to the list</param>
    ''' <param name="value">the current list being built</param>
    ''' <param name="output">a list of all possible combinations</param>
    Private Sub Combine(source As List(Of String), length As Integer, value As List(Of String), output As List(Of List(Of String)))
        For i As Integer = 0 To source.Count - 1
            value.Add(source(i))
            If length <= 1 Then
                'Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", value))
                output.Add(New List(Of String)(value))
            Else
                Combine(source, length - 1, value, output)
            End If
            value.RemoveAt(value.Count - 1)
        Next
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' returns only unique patterns
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="list"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Function Filter(list As List(Of List(Of String))) As List(Of String)
        Dim found As New HashSet(Of String)

        For Each item As List(Of String) In list
            Dim temp As New List(Of String)(item)
            temp.Sort()
            Dim s As String = String.Join(", ", temp)
            If Not found.Contains(s) Then
                found.Add(s)
            End If
        Next
        Return New List(Of String)(found)
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: This is not homework at all. I am a hobbyist programmer. I won't deny that I have years of experience. I will check out the HashSet class, as this is what I needed. Thanks

Comment: Please can you give me some code. I am stuck as to how I can declare the arrays that contain the combinations. Thanks

Comment: @OliverScott-Brown If you want to use an array then you can calculate how many permutations you are going to generate in advance: [Combinations and Permutations](http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html). Or you could use a [List(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will expand automatically as you add items to it.